# How to install latest version of rgedit in 13.04

Tags: installation, 13.04, gedit, r

I've got a [bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286421/plotting-not-working-well-in-with-rgedit-in-13-04-bug) in the version of [RGedit](http://rgedit.sourceforge.net/) in ubuntu's repository and I want to install the [latest version](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rgedit/files/) to see if this plays better with 13.04 somehow.

What do I do once I download the archive?  Where do I put it?  Do I need to uninstall the old version of rgedit that was installed via the "software center"?

FOR POSTERITY:  If anyone else has the same problem, note that updating to the latest version of RGedit does not solve the problem with plotting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `README` file on [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rgedit/files/ReadMe.txt/download):

To install, extract the RgeditXX.tar.bz2 archive somewhere and, depending on your
gedit's major version, copy the contents of the resulting folder into to your
 ~/.gnome2/gedit/plugins folder for gedit2, and ~/.local/share/gedit/plugins for gedit3. That folder should now contain:

- RCtrl (this is a folder)
- RCtrl.gedit-plugin
- RCtrl.py
- ReadMe.txt (this ReadMe.txt file)

If you installed the older verison through the software center, I'd recommend uninstalling it the same way before doing the above.

Comment: Right.  What is gedit's "major version"?  I actually found a folder with a lot of plugins for gedit and copied the contents using gksudo nautilus, but then the plugin became inoperable.  Does the result change when I use terminal commands to move things?  Do I need to use an extract command that extracts the files somewhere different from where the archive is?  Does this make a difference?

Comment: "Major version" is the first digit of the version number (in gedit, menu command `Help > About` will show your version number).  Your comment is unclear as to whether you *copied* the contents of the plugins folder, or *moved* them.  If you moved them, put them back. Then extract `RgeditXX.tar.bz2` onto your Desktop, open the resulting folder, and move the contents of that folder into the location indicated in the instructions above.

Comment: Another wrinkle:  my major version is 3, but there is no ~/.local/share/gedit/plugins folder.  Or any "gedit" folder in /.local/share.  The other gedit plugins (latex, etc) are elsewhere.  Indeed, I found the repository version of the RGedit plugin elsewhere in some obscure sudo-only directory.

Comment: nevermind, it works to just make the folder, but only after I reboot.